# Opening a file after changing its extension

Tags: c#

I want to open a file after changing its extension. The extension is changed, but it can't find the file to open, so how would I find it?
What I have so far:

```
filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
File.Move(filePath, Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".csv"));
FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the return value from `Path.ChangeExtension`:

```
filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
var newFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, ".csv");
File.Move(filePath, newFilePath);
FileStream stream = File.Open(newFilePath, FileMode.Open);
```

The above code opens the file inside your application.

If you want the Windows Shell to open the file by using Excel, OpenOffice, etc. you can do this, among other ways.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newFilePath);
```

Comment: Extension is changed but file doesn't open

Comment: @MichelFaraday can you be more specific when you say "doesn't open"?

Comment: Yes. When a file is initially selected, the conversion is made, but does not open in Excel, which is what I'm trying to open.